# knockout.js and disabling anchor tag

Tags: knockout.js, anchor, javascript

How can I disable and enable an anchor tag with this custom binding.  It works great with input elements but the anchor tag just changes the CSS, not the disabling.

```
<a href="link" data-bind="myDisabled: !enabled()"/>

ko.bindingHandlers.myDisabled = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        ko.bindingHandlers.css.update(element, function() {return { disabled: value }; });
        ko.bindingHandlers.disable.update(element, valueAccessor);
    }
};
```

Comment: I've only seen anchor tags "disabled" by setting their onlick to false. What is it you mean want to happen to the anchor to "disable" it?

Comment: Just to make sure it doesnt fire any click events, and when enabled, the click events are renabled.

Comment: As an alternative you can use KOs comment logic to just produce a different tag. See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15969045/52551

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to capture click event in your binding handler.

**HTML**:

```
<a href="link" data-bind="disableClick: !enabled()">test</a>
<br/><br/><br/>
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: enabled"> enabled ​
```

**JavaScript**:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.disableClick = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {

        $(element).click(function(evt) {
            if(valueAccessor())
                evt.preventDefault();
        });

    },

    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {        
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        ko.bindingHandlers.css.update(element, function() {return { disabled_anchor: value }; });
    }
};

ko.applyBindings({ enabled: ko.observable(false)});
```

​

Here is a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/kp74u/54/

**UPDATE 1**: If you need to prevent other event handlers bound after knockout binding handler was attached, you need to add `stopImmediatePropagation` to the event handler along with `preventDefault`.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/kp74u/55/

**UPDATE 2**: If you want to disable all event handlers (along with click event handlers attached before your binding handler, you need to 'hack' the jquery events array). Please note that this may not work other versions of jquery (example uses 1.7):

```
ko.bindingHandlers.disableClick = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {

        $(element).click(function(evt) {
            alert('test before');
        });

        $(element).click(function(evt) {
            if (valueAccessor()) {
                evt.preventDefault();
                evt.stopImmediatePropagation();
            }
        });

        //begin of 'hack' to move our 'disable' event handler to top of the stack
        var events = $.data(element, "events");
        console.log(events);
        var handlers = events['click'];

        if (handlers.length == 1) {
            return;
        }

        handlers.splice(0, 0, handlers.pop());
        //end of 'hack' to move our 'disable' event handler to top of the stack


        $(element).click(function(evt) {
            alert('test after');
        });
    },

    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        ko.bindingHandlers.css.update(element, function() {
            return {
                disabled_anchor: value
            };
        });
    }
};
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/nickolsky/kp74u/40/

**UPDATE 3**: As was mentioned there ([suggested edit by FIR55TORM](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2241922), sorry can't approve this completely correct edit because I am too late to review): if you're using jQuery 1.10.x, you will need to add an underscore to access the 'data' object like so:

```
var events = $._data(element, "events");
```

Revised fiddle for jQuery 1.10.x: http://jsfiddle.net/nickolsky/kp74u/41/

Comment: As of jQuery 1.8 you can no longer access the data via that API. Replace with `jQuery._data(key, value)`

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer when goggling for a way of doing this, but I didn't like the approach so did my own

```
var orgClickInit = ko.bindingHandlers.click.init;
ko.bindingHandlers.click.init = function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
    if (element.tagName === "A" && allBindingsAccessor().enable != null) {
        var disabled = ko.computed(function () {
            return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor().enable) === false;
        });
        ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { css: { disabled: disabled} });
        var handler = valueAccessor();
        valueAccessor = function () {
            return function () {
                if (ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor().enable)) {
                    handler.apply(this, arguments);
                }
            }
        };

    }
    orgClickInit(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel);
};
```

Its seamless with the native click and enable binding (disable binding not implemented)
Fiddle (Fiddle also uses my Convention over configuration library)
http://jsfiddle.net/xCfQC/30/

Comment: Really liked this idea, the main drawback is you must define a "click" method for it to work. See my answer for a solution where it works with or without click defined.

Answer (score 0):

Using @Anders answer as inspiration, I came up with my own version of this. Allows for use of "enable", "disable" with or without the "click". Also allows for a custom disabled class, otherwise defaults to "disabled".

```
var koEnableUpdateOrig = ko.bindingHandlers.enable.update;
ko.bindingHandlers.enable.update = function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
    // call original enable update
    var result = koEnableUpdateOrig.apply(this, arguments);
    var enabled = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());

    // get and apply disabled class
    var disabledClass = "disabled";
    if (allBindings)
        disabledClass = allBindings().disabledClass || "disabled";
    if (enabled) {
        $(element).removeClass(disabledClass);
        if (element.tagName === "A")
            $(element).off("click.koEnableUpdate");
    }
    else {
        $(element).addClass(disabledClass);
        if (element.tagName === "A")
            $(element).on("click.koEnableUpdate", function (e) { e.preventDefault(); });
    }

    return result;
};
ko.bindingHandlers.disable.update = function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
    // call enable with the reverse value
    // the original knockout disable does this, but does not pass the allBindings
    ko.bindingHandlers.enable.update(element, function () {
        return !ko.unwrap(valueAccessor())
    }, allBindings);
};

var koClickInitOrig = ko.bindingHandlers.click.init;
ko.bindingHandlers.click.init = function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
    // wrap click function with enable/disable check
    var valueAccessorOrig = valueAccessor();
    valueAccessor = function () {
        return function () {
            if (ko.unwrap(allBindings().enable) ||
                (allBindings().disable == null || !ko.unwrap(allBindings().disable))) {
                valueAccessorOrig.apply(this, arguments);
            }
        }
    };

    // apply wrapped click to original click init
    koClickInitOrig.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

Comment: Cant really see the usecase when you want enable/disable without a click handler :D Here is a version supporting disable http://jsfiddle.net/xCfQC/31/

Comment: @Anders When you have an anchor with a set href and no need for click. That was my situation.

Comment: But the href will still execute, its only css? You need to return false from the click handler for it not to fire, you could fix that in your wrapper clikc handler

Comment: @Anders You're right... added code to handle that. Was able to do it without needing the knockout click handler.

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach:

**JavaScript**

```
(function () {
  var originalDisableUpdate = ko.bindingHandlers.disable.update;

  ko.bindingHandlers.disable.update = function (element, valueAccessor) {
      if (element.tagName === 'A') {
        var
          value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
          disabled = 'disabled';

        if (value) {
          element.setAttribute(disabled, null);
        }
        else {
          element.removeAttribute(disabled);
        }
      }
      else {
        originalDisableUpdate(element, valueAccessor);
      }
  };
})();
```

**CSS**

```
a[disabled] {
  pointer-events:none;
  cursor:default;
}
```