# Disable anchor tag in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I need to disable the anchor tag inside a foreach loop of knockout.js in HTML.

Here is my code:

```
<a id="aQStreamSkype" data-bind="attr:{href: ''}, click: $parent.StoreUserClick,disable: ($data.SkypeId == 'null')">Skype </a>
```

Answer (score 27):

**Anchor tags cannot be disabled**.
 The easiest is to use `ko if binding` and then render a `span` instead of the `anchor` if the skype id is null

```
<!-- ko if: skypeId === null -->
    <span >No Skype Id</span>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: skypeId !== null -->
    <a id="aQStreamSkype" data-bind="attr:{href: ''}, click: $parent.StoreUserClick,text: skypeId"></a>
<!-- /ko -->
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sujesharukil/w9SHz/1/)

Answer (score 14):

If there is no `href` attribute on `a` element but only an action in a `click binding`, then an easy way would be passing expression `condition && handler` to a click binding.

If condition is observable you'll need to add parentheses.

```
<a data-bind="click: flag1() && handler">Enabled link</a>
<a data-bind="click: flag2() && handler">Disabled link</a>
```

It will be evaluated as `false` if condition is `false` (so nothing will happen), 
 and will be evaluated as a handler if condition is `true`.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/83kkjnbg/1/)

Answer (score 6):

First off, there's a school of thought with which I have some sympathy that says [just don't do it](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-disable-links/#article-header-id-0). A hyperlink that does nothing is just text.

However, I can see the flip side of the coin - I came across this same problem because I am using a Bootstrap dropdown menu which contains anchor tags as menu options, and to my mind it gives a better user experience to show the menu options as disabled rather than just not show them at all, and I feel it's cleaner to 'disable' the hyperlink than to include markup for a hyperlink and a `span` with the same text and then conditionally show one or the other. So, my solution was:

```
<a data-bind="click: checkCondition() ? myFunction : null, css: { disabled: !checkCondition() }"></a>
```

Note that `checkCondition()` is a function which returns true or false, indcating whether the hyperlink should be enabled or not. The `css` binding is just styling the hyperlink to appear disabled - you may have to add your own `.disabled` CSS class if you're not using Bootstrap.

The key to this working is that the anchor has no `href` attribute, so it's useless as a hyperlink without the Knockout `click` binding, which means that you could just as easily use this method with any element type (e.g. this could be a clickable `span` as easily as an anchor). However, I wanted to use an anchor so that my styling continued to be applied without any extra work.

Comment: Works well with appropriate CSS, e.g. `a.disabled { pointer-events: none; opacity: 0.6; }` (meaning that you don't need a conditional click handler).

Answer (score 2):

Disable only works with form elements, not anchor tags. You could use the [visible](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/visible-binding.html) binding instead, and just hide the link if there is no user id. If you do want to show something even if there isn't a user id, then add a span with the opposite visible test, then one will be shown if there is a user id, and the other if there isn't:

```
<a id="aQStreamSkype" data-bind="attr:{href: ''}, click: $parent.StoreUserClick, visible: ($data.SkypeId !== 'null')">Skype </a>
<span class="notLink" data-bind="visible: ($data.SkypeId === 'null')">Skype </span>
```

As a side note, if SkypeId is an observable, you will need to call it as one in your comparison check:

```
($data.SkypeId() !== 'null')
```

Comment: Can i make a span disable?

Comment: No, just things like input, textarea, select. If you really want to display something, you could add a span in after the anchor tag, and make that visible only if there isn't a skype user id, so you'd show the anchor if there is one, and the span if there isn't. I'll add that to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

With some override magic you can get this behaviour without that your view or ViewModel code need changes

```
  (function () {
      var orgClickInit = ko.bindingHandlers.click.init;
      ko.bindingHandlers.click.init = function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
          if (element.tagName === "A" && allBindingsAccessor().enable != null) {
              var disabled = ko.computed(function () {
                  return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor().enable) === false;
              });
              ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { css: { disabled: disabled} });
              var handler = valueAccessor();
              valueAccessor = function () {
                  return function () {
                      if (ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor().enable)) {
                          handler.apply(this, arguments);
                      }
                  }
              };

          }
          orgClickInit(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel);
      };
  })();
```

When you include that code the enable binding will work for anhors

Fiddle, it uses my convention library so ignore that part
http://jsfiddle.net/xCfQC/4/

Comment: I had issue with this, but got it working as per my comment here http://stackoverflow.com/a/17322681/661584

Comment: I had issue with this, but got it working as per my comment here http://stackoverflow.com/a/17322681/661584

Answer (score 0):

Knockout enable/disable binding **do not support anchor tags**.

So you have 2 solution to this.

**Solution 1**

```
<a href='#' title="Skype" data-bind='click: function() { 
 if(($data.SkypeId !== 'null'))
 {
    //call the desired method from here
 }' >
```

**Solution 2**

This button displays only when your condition is success and it has click binding

```
<a data-bind="click: $parent.StoreUserClick, visible: ($data.SkypeId != 'null')" href="#" title="Skype">
```

This button displays only when your negative condition is success and it do not have click binding

```
<a data-bind="visible: ($data.SkypeId == 'null')" href="#" title="Skype ">
```

Answer (score 0):

I found [ko.plus](https://github.com/stevegreatrex/ko.plus) an excellent library which implements command pattern. The 'action' can not be executed until 'canExecute' condition is true.

```js
var vm = {
    enabled: ko.observable(false),
    StoreUserClick: ko.command({
        action: function () {
            window.alert('Command is active')
        },
        canExecute: function () {
            return vm.enabled();
        }
    })
}
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```css
a.disabled {
    color: gray;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stevegreatrex/ko.plus/master/dist/ko.plus.js"></script>

<a href="" id="aQStreamSkype" data-bind="click: StoreUserClick, css: { disabled: !StoreUserClick.canExecute() }">Skype</a>
<br />
<br />
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: enabled">enabled
```

Answer (score -1):

Another option that I like to use is to disable the anchor using the **"css"** directive:

```
<a id="aQStreamSkype" data-bind="css: { disabled: $data.SkypeId == 'null' }">Skype</a>
```

Comment: This will only style the link to appear disabled. If the user clicks on the link it'll still do whatever is bound to the `click` event.