# Enable condition for click binding

Tags: knockout.js

Is there any way to specify an enable condition for the click binding? For example if I have the following:

```
<div data-bind="click: toggleDialog">Click Me</div>
```

I'd like to be able to disable clicking if a specified condition occurs so something to the effect of:

```
<div data-bind="click: toggleDialog, enableClick: myName() === 'John'">Click Me</div>
```

I'm thinking maybe a custom binding would work for this, but not quite exactly sure how to go about doing it.

Comment: Why don't you start the `toggleDialog` function with the check `myName() === 'John'`?

Comment: Yeah, that's a possibility. I call my toggleDialog function from other places in my code though and I want those calls to work even if `myName() !== 'John'`. I was trying to avoid adding a `clickToggleDialog` function which then calls `toggleDialog` if `myName() === 'John'`, but that might just be the best solution.

Comment: Kyle, in that case you want to disable the button, not the dialog function.  Take a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use this approach that I did for anchors

http://jsfiddle.net/xCfQC/11/

```
(function() {
    //First make KO able to disable clicks on Anchors
    var orgClickInit = ko.bindingHandlers.click.init;
    ko.bindingHandlers.click.init = function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
      if(element.tagName === "DIV" && allBindingsAccessor().enable != null) {
          var disabled = ko.computed({
              read: function() {
                  return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor().enable) === false;                                     
              }, 
              disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved: element
          });
          ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { css: { disabled: disabled}  });
          var handler = valueAccessor(); 
          valueAccessor = function() {
              return function() {
                  if(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor().enable)) { 
                      handler.apply(this, arguments);   
                  }
              }
          };         
      } 
      orgClickInit.apply(this, arguments);
    };
})();
```

More details:
https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.BindingConventions/wiki/Button-convention

Comment: Thanks! I cleaned it up a bit and added a disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved to the disable computed. See edit

Comment: Note: the disabled css attribute won't update if the condition is not a simple observable (something like "enable: myCount() > 3")

Comment: Also, you might want to remove the element.tagName === "DIV" condition so that it works on other elements (like a)

Comment: What I mean is that the disabled css attribute won't update if the condition is put in the html like this: [http://jsfiddle.net/leszekhanusz/hx972/](http://jsfiddle.net/leszekhanusz/hx972/)

Comment: Ok, first of you shouldn't put logic in the view, that's the reason you have the viewmodel. Anyway, if you want that behaviour you need to override the enable binding and put the css logic there

Comment: I was getting exception "knockout-3.4.0.debug.js:4188 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$data' of undefined" when using this, I got it to work by adding the bindingContext argument to the third line e.g. 

ko.bindingHandlers.click.init = function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext ) {

Answer (score 3):

It's actually a good amount simpler than any of these options.   You can't make the binding conditional but you can make what function is fired conditional. Just use a conditional in the binding:

```
<div data-bind="click: myName() === 'John' ? toggleDialog : function(){ /* Nothing Happens */}">Click Me</div>
```

That will either fire `toggleDialog()` or an anonymous `function(){}` that does nothing.

You can even stack bound properties to disable the button itself:

```
<div data-bind="
    disabled: myName() !== 'John',
    click: myName() === 'John' ? toggleDialog : function(){ /* Nothing Happens */}
">Click Me</div>
```

Or have another function that runs in response to an unmet condition:

```
<div data-bind="
    disabled: myName() !== 'John',
    click: myName() === 'John' ? toggleDialog : tellUserTheyAreWrong
">Click Me</div>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I've recently done this and put the condition check into the click function itself, so it won't do anything unless the condition is met. I also then use a computed function to provide the css class for the element, and change the cursor dependent on whether the element will react to the click:

In my view model:

```
iconStyle = ko.computed(function () {
    var cssClass = 'DefaultClass';
     if (/*condition to check if click is valid*/) {
        cssClass = cssClass + ' Off';
     }

    return cssClass;
})
```

Then bind like this:

```
<div class="stepIcon" data-bind="click: clickFunction, css: iconStyle"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Kyle, after reading your comment to nemsev, I believe you want to disable your button, not your dialog function.

The binding...

```
<button data-bind="click: doAlert, enable: allowAlert">Open Dialog</button>
<div data-bind="click: doAlert">Click me for another call to trigger the dialog</div>
<button data-bind="click: toggleAllowAlert, text: allowButtonText"></button>
```

And the code...

```
var viewModel = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.allowAlert = ko.observable(true);
    self.allowButtonText = ko.computed(function(){
        if(self.allowAlert()){ 
            return 'Turn off button'; 
        } else { 
            return 'Turn on button'; 
        }
    });
    self.toggleAllowAlert = function(){
        self.allowAlert(!self.allowAlert());
    };
    self.doAlert = function(){
        alert('The dialog has opened');
    };
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DQg5P/1/

Comment: Thanks. This would work for a `button`. Unfortunately, in my case due to some restrictions I'm under based on a UI framework I'm working with a clickable `div`.

Comment: In that case, same theory but different implementation.  The "enable" binding wont work on a div, but you'd still want to disable only the click handler for the div and not the dialog function itself.  That way your other code can still fire the dialog.